# C# String Replacement not working

Tags: c#, string, replace

I am trying to replace a string content with another but it does not replace

```
string oldValue= "iif([PricingTKt_US]>0,1-([F221-B01]/iif([PricingTKt_US]=0,1, [PricingTKt_US])),0)"; 

oldValue=oldValue.Replace("[PricingTkt_US]","[F123]")
```

Please help me to understand the mistake I am doing.

Comment: you have a lower case K vs an upper case one.

Comment: Learn to debug your code, both using a debugger and in other ways. That means experimenting, such as trying the same thing with simpler strings to see if the logic works in the first place. If it does, that means there's something wrong with your strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string oldValue= "iif([PricingTKt_US]>0,1-([F221-B01]/iif([PricingTKt_US]=0,1, [PricingTKt_US])),0)";
```

`PricingTKt_US` Capital `K`.

```
oldValue=oldValue.Replace("[PricingTkt_US]","[F123]")
```

`PricingTkt_US` Small `k`